Need advise regarding my own flask project
I am working on a python Flask project, in where the core idea is to verify the image uploaded by the user and make sure it's not fake or they are plagiarized.
The help i need regarding is - User uploads the pic of a plant , i want to make sure that , they have only taken the picture, not from internet or copied from another person in the same platform. I have some preliminary checks but they are not enough, can anyone advise me on what more can i do ? I have done these mentioned below:
A) Done image quality check
B) Web detection
C)Database duplicate detection
D)Using latitude and longitude (failed miserably, accuracy difference of 2KM)
E)Making sure the image is plant only
Since the location method is not working, i have that loophole, i don't need it to be super security level but as long something similar to accurate location detection or any similar technique to make sure the image is really from the user. Would love to have some advise . Thankyou !
This is the location code:
# EXIF extraction functions
def get_exif_data(image_path):
    """Get embedded EXIF data from image file using ExifRead."""
    with open(image_path, 'rb') as image_file:
        tags = exifread.process_file(image_file)
    return tags

def get_gps_data(tags):
    """Extract GPS data from EXIF tags."""
    gps_data = {}
    gps_keys = ['GPS GPSLatitude', 'GPS GPSLatitudeRef', 'GPS GPSLongitude', 'GPS GPSLongitudeRef']
    for key in gps_keys:
        if key in tags:
            gps_data[key] = tags[key]
    return gps_data

def convert_to_degrees(value):
    """Convert GPS coordinates to degrees, avoiding zero division."""
    def safe_div(num, den):
        return float(num) / float(den) if den != 0 else 0

    if len(value.values) != 3:
        print("Incomplete GPS coordinate data.")
        return None

    d = safe_div(value.values[0].num, value.values[0].den)
    m = safe_div(value.values[1].num, value.values[1].den)
    s = safe_div(value.values[2].num, value.values[2].den)
    return d + (m / 60.0) + (s / 3600.0)

def get_lat_lon(gps_data):
    """Extract latitude and longitude from GPS data."""
    lat = None
    lon = None

    gps_latitude = gps_data.get('GPS GPSLatitude')
    gps_latitude_ref = gps_data.get('GPS GPSLatitudeRef')
    gps_longitude = gps_data.get('GPS GPSLongitude')
    gps_longitude_ref = gps_data.get('GPS GPSLongitudeRef')

    if gps_latitude and gps_latitude_ref and gps_longitude and gps_longitude_ref:
        lat = convert_to_degrees(gps_latitude)
        lon = convert_to_degrees(gps_longitude)

        if lat is None or lon is None:
            return None, None

        if gps_latitude_ref.values[0] != 'N':
            lat = -lat
        if gps_longitude_ref.values[0] != 'E':
            lon = -lon

    return lat, lon

def extract_gps_from_image(image_path):
    tags = get_exif_data(image_path)
    gps_data = get_gps_data(tags)
    lat, lon = get_lat_lon(gps_data)
    return lat, lon



they have only taken the picture, not from internet or copied from
another person in the same platform

I suggest giving a try dhash

I’ve found that dhash is great for detecting near duplicates (we found
dupes using a size 8 dhash with a maximum delta of 2 bits). But
because of the simplicity of the algorithm, it’s not great at finding
similar images or duplicate-but-cropped images – you’d need a more
sophisticated image fingerprint if you want that. However, the dhash
is good for finding exact duplicates and near duplicates, for example,
the same image with slightly altered lighting, a few pixels of
cropping, or very light photoshopping.


I have noted down using dhash, it could help me find duplicates. would love to hear more image techniques to make sure its from the user's phone or mobile itself and not from the AI or any other sources. Thanks a lot for the advise.
